# Why is this number placeholder not working?

Tags: python-3.x

I have written a script that takes user input at the command line and performs a calculation to determine somebody's approximate age.

What I can't understand is why this portion of it is going wrong (`invalid syntax` error):

```
print("That makes you approximately %d years old", % (int(year - int(sys.argv[2]))))
```

The full script is as follows:

```
from datetime import date
import sys

greeting = sys.argv[1]
year = int(date.today().year)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("This script is called: ", sys.argv[0])
    print("Your message is: ", greeting)
    print("Your year of birth is: ", sys.argv[2])
    print("That makes you approximately %d years old", % (int(year - int(sys.argv[2]))))
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`%` is a binary operator whose first operand must be a string. In the end there is one comma too many:

```
print("format %d", % (num))  # wrong
print("format %d" % (num))  # correct
```

in addition to that, you might be surprised that the parentheses here do nothing:

```
print("format %d" % num)  # also correct
```

that's a strange side effect of this not being something function call-like, but an operator. It also means that the second operand is a tuple in general, to allow multiple formatting operands:

```
print("format %d" % (num,))  # the best way
```

Why is that better? Take this example:

```
tup = ()
print("format %s" % tup)  # TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
print("format %s" % (tup))  # same
print("format %s" % (tup,))  # correct
```

That's one of the reasons I prefer the newer format function, or even better f-strings.